# Why am I getting 'Invariant unproven' warning

Tags: c#, code-contracts

I don't get what this message is trying to tell me:

```
CodeContracts: invariant unproven: _uiRoot != null && _uiRoot.Children != null && _uiRoot.RowDefinitions != null && _uiRoot.ColumnDefinitions != null
```

This is the method:

```
private void AddRowToGrid(List<UIElement> row) {

        Contract.Requires(row != null);

        _uiRoot.RowDefinitions.Add(new RowDefinition());
        VerifyColumnCount(row.Count);

        int colunmn = 0;
        foreach (UIElement uiElement in row.Where(element => element != null))
        {
            if (uiElement != null)
            {
                uiElement.SetValue(Grid.ColumnProperty, colunmn++);
                if (_uiRoot.RowDefinitions != null)
                {
                    uiElement.SetValue(Grid.RowProperty, _uiRoot.RowDefinitions.Count - 1);
                    if (_uiRoot.Children != null)
                    {
                        _uiRoot.Children.Add(uiElement);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

This is the Invariant:

```
[ContractInvariantMethod]
    private void ObjectInvariant() {
        Contract.Invariant(_layoutList != null && this._layoutList.DefaultLayoutItemEntities != null);
        Contract.Invariant(_uiRoot != null && _uiRoot.Children != null && _uiRoot.RowDefinitions != null &&
                           _uiRoot.ColumnDefinitions != null);
        Contract.Invariant(_dragDropManager != null);
    }
```

I have tried adding the following Contract.Ensures, but it still gives me the same message:

```
 Contract.Ensures(_uiRoot != null && _uiRoot.Children != null && _uiRoot.RowDefinitions != null &&
                         _uiRoot.ColumnDefinitions != null);
```

Comment: And what is `_uiroot` ? Field/Property, what class? Any contreacts on that class?

Comment: It's an instance of a Silverlight Grid.  There are no contracts on anything else in the project (just getting started with CC).

Comment: What is the message after breaking the invariant into 4 invariants?

Answer (score 1):

What I have learned is that to prove the correctness to the static analyzer, you need to either have a check in code, such as:

```
if(_uiRoot == null || _uiRoot.Children == null || _uiRoot.RowDefinitions == null ||
                     _uiRoot.ColumnDefinitions == null)
      throw new Exception();
```

The analyzer will see this and decide that this is proof of the Contact.Ensures.

The other option is to use:

```
Contract.Assume(_uiRoot != null && _uiRoot.Children != null && _uiRoot.RowDefinitions != null &&
                     _uiRoot.ColumnDefinitions != null);
```

This will tell the analyzer that the Contract.Ensure has been proven, and also, at runtime, if runtime checking is enabled, it will verify that it is true.

Better yet is writing the code so that the analyzer can prove by analyzing the code itself.  This to me is the greatest benefit of Code Contracts - code that proves itself because it is well written.

Greg

Comment: "code that proves itself"... could you give an example of this?